# How to assign a single char to a char array

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, char

This code works:

```
char Str[2] = "S";
    
printf("%c\n", Str[0]);
Str[0] = 'T';
printf("%c\n", Str[0]);


-----
S
T
```

But this doesn't:

```
char *Str = "S";
    
printf("%c\n", Str[0]);
Str[0] = 'T';
printf("%c\n", Str[0]);


------
S
Segmentation fault
```

Why did the second version fail? Doesn't `char Str[2] = "S"` decay into `char *Str = "S"` so the two versions of code should be equivalent?
Why did the compiler not pick up any error?

My second question is:
What is the most efficient way of consecutively adding a number of single chars to a string (char array)?

Comment: Regarding the first question, see the linked FAQ duplicate. The difference is where the data is allocated. For the second question, the fastest is (probably) always to directly write `S[i] = some_character;` and then move the null terminator accordingly. Note that your first example does not use a C string btw, since you didn't leave room for the null terminator to get allocated.

Comment: @Lundin I wasn't seeing a difference in results whether using ```Str[1]``` or ```Str[2]```, but I'll edit the first example accordingly.

Comment: That's because C allows you to initialize a character array based on a string literal `"..."` without providing enough space for the null terminator. You will then not get a proper C string, but something else. The historical reasons for this is that back in the dinosaur age when C was designed, Unix allowed a different kind of string format with fixed lengths, that stored the size separately.

Comment: @Lundin That's really interesting to know. In my example, what compiler option do I need to use, so that the error gets picked up?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such option - the problem being that this is valid C and so the compiler must accept it. However, you could declare the string as `char str[] = "...";` in which case it will be made large enough to fit the null terminator.

Comment: @Lundin I meant, what compiler option do I need to use so that: ```char *Str = "S";
Str[0] = 'T';``` gets flagged as an error, because its trying to write 'T' to ROM.

Comment: If you are declaring a pointer to a literal, use `const`. Then you will get a compiler error if you try to write to it.

Comment: @stark The question is why does the compiler allow you to write to what will obviously be non-writable memory.

Comment: Because the standard requires it.  Modifying a string literal is implementation-defined and allowed in some implementations.